# Storing and displaying dates in a script (bash)

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

On my Linux (Ubuntu) I have a very simple backup script, essentially:

```
rsync <params> dir_src_a dir_dest_b
rsync <params> dir_src_aa dir_dest_bb
rsync <params> dir_src_aaa dir_dest_bbb
```

What I'd like to do, is before each rsync runs, store the current date/time in a variable (obviously a different var for each rsync) then when the last rsync has finished, print up on screen something like:

```
rsync 1 started at startdate
rsync 2 started at startdate
rsync 3 started at startdate
```

I have zero scripting skills so any guidance would be appreciated.  The script currently is just in standard bash and on Ubuntu 18.04, doubt that matters though.  Thanks!

Comment: Zero scripting skills, learn scripting: http://tldp.org/guides.html -> "Bash Guide for Beginners" and then "Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide" - as you grasp the very basics you will be scripting in no time.

Comment: I don't have a need to write very many scripts.  This is simply a time-saver so I don't have to run several different-but-similar commands whenever I do backups.  Telling me to "go learn how to script" doesn't really help.

Comment: That is a resource pointer, nothing else. ;-) With just a tiny bit of effort you'll be creating your own special scripts.

Answer (score 0):

See the `date` command. You can put the current date/time in a string like this:

```
now=$(date)
```

Or restrict that to just the time:

```
now=$(date +%H:%M:%S)
```

In a script you put these values in an array:

```
#!/bin/bash

# declare array
set -a times

# Loop over the directories
for d in dir1 dir2 dir3
do
  # Add the current time at the end of the array
  times[${#times[*]}]=$(date +%H:%M:%S)
  # Perform rsync (replace next two by actual code)
  echo rsync $d
  sleep 2
done

# Loop over array of start times, "${!times[@]}" produces a 0-based sequence of indices over the array
for i in "${!times[@]}"; 
do 
  # Print the time ( "$((i+1))" increments the number because unlike computers, humans counts from 1)
  printf "Rsync of dir #%s started at %s\n" "$((i+1))" "${times[$i]}"
done
```

There are many options to format the date. If you go further in your scripting, the most useful one is `%s` that gives "seconds since the Epoch", which is very useful (and really the only safe way) to compute durations.

Comment: Thanks, that seems the way to go... not bothered about computing the durations, I can do that mentally by looking at the times.  As @KamilMaciorowski mentioned, the steps needed to store/print this would be awesome!